# Select group of columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table with some columns and data (showed in asp.net mvc 3 View).
I want to select a group of columns and then pass and show those columns and their data to another view.

How can I do that?

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Container').jtable({            
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("ShowList")'
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '23%'
            },
            IsActive: {
                title: 'Active',
                width: '23%'
            }                
        }
    });

    $('#Container').jtable('load');
});
```

Comment: Is the table bound to an underlying JavaScript object or straight HTML?

Comment: I showed data using jtable. But when I click the column header, it's sort function. I removed sort function and now I want to select group of column. P/S: Added code

Answer (score 0):

simple way to do that. Just add a multiselect list which allow user select multi options. Then get the value of options and pass them to view

Here's some code:

```
//add multiselect list
<select multiple="multiple" class="selc">
        <option value="Product">Product</option>
        <option value="Category">Category</option>
        <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>
        <option value="UnitPrice">Unit Price</option>
        <option value="Total">Total</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" />

//add some script to get values
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var s = $('.selc').val();            
        $('#view2').empty();
        LoadPage(s);
    });
});

function LoadPage(arr) {
    $('#view2').append('<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="420" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    $('iframe#frame1').attr('src', '../Home/Page.aspx?s=' + arr);
}
```

any better solutions?